# How do I initialize a vector member of a struct?

Tags: c++, struct

Suppose I have a struct with a member that is a vector. In the constructor, I want to just set it to NULL. But then later I want to be able to push_back things to it. How do I initialize the vector after it's NULL?

```
struct structName {
    vector<int> vec;
    structName() {
        vec = NULL
    }
    void set(int);
}

void structName::set(int n) {
    // What do I put here?
    vec.push_back(n);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

It's already initialized via the default constructor and, if you need to call a different constructor, use an initialization list.

Remember, this is C++, not Java/C#/whatever.  It makes no sense for an *object* to be null (ok, it doesn't in those languages either, but read on).  It can't happen. In Java and languages like it you have variables which are references to objects and those *references* (not objects!) may or may not be null.

That is not the case in C++.  There is a strict delineation between objects and pointers which refer to them (and pointers, or course, can be null or refer to an invalid memory location).

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor for the vector will set it to its simplest state: no contents. So just leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a vector to NULL doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you're getting confused with pointers. If you want to initialize your vector to the *empty vector* then that happens automatically. Like this in other words

```
struct structName {
    vector<int> vec;
    structName() {
    }
    void set(int);
}

void structName::set(int n) {
    vec.push_back(n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense... I'm using this to make a hash table. Will empty vectors take up too much space do you think?

Comment: I would expect (on a 32 bit machine) for an empty vector to take up 12 bytes. But if you want to test this try `sizeof(vector<int>)`.

Comment: @john: 20 in VS2010, just an FYI.  user17... vectors aren't big. Their backing data store can *get* big, but the vector itself is small.

Comment: @EdS. 20 bytes in debug mode, but 16 bytes in release mode. Still slightly disappointing. I think a good implementation would only use 12. Point about the backing data is correct of course but I would expect a default constructed empty vector to have precisely zero bytes allocated for the data.

Comment: @john: D'oh!  Can't believe I left it in Debug... and yeah, I would expect the same for an empty vector of course.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012's `std::vector` size is 12, as per [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you be thinking of C++ objects like you would in Java. **DON'T** They are totally different beasts.

In C++, objects aren't references as in Java, thus, nulling them out doesn't make sense. In fact trying `vec = NULL` is an error as `NULL` is really just 0.

Instead just remove the line `vec = NULL` and it'll work as is. The vector will be default constructed as empty and you don't have to do any other initialization.